# What is a regex for usernames having letters, no spaces or numbers with a certain length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

What is a regular expression to allow letters only, with no spaces or numbers, with a length of 20 characters?

Some examples of acceptable usernames:

```
ask1kew
supacool
sec1entertainment
ThatPerson1
Alexking
```

Some examples of unacceptable usernames:

```
No_problem1
a_a_sidkd
Thenamethatismorethen20characterslong
```

Comment: What "letters"? Latin only? Unicode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work if you're limiting yourself to ASCII:

```
/\A[a-z0-9]{,20}\z/i
```

That will also match an empty string though so you might want to add a lower limit (5 in this example):

```
/\A[a-z0-9]{5,20}\z/i
```

If you wanted to be adventurous and allow non-ASCII letters and you're using Ruby 1.9 then you could use this:

```
/\A\p{Alnum}{5,20}\z/
/\A\p{Alnum}{,20}\z/   # If no lower limit on length is desired.
```

Answer (score 1):

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}$`

`{1,20}` is `{min, max}` so you could set it to `{5,20}` to limit it to minimum of 5 chars and a max of 20.